# How does cx_Freeze detect the virtual environments/dependencies?

Tags: python, dependency-management, cx-freeze, virtual-environment

I just succeeded to build `.exe` file with cx_Freeze.
The only problem is that **the size of the build folder(incl. .exe, .ui, libraries) is too large(1.02GB)** in spite of a few functions. And I found that the folder called **numpy_mkl takes up a large proportion(745MB)** of the build folder.

Because Anaconda is installed on my PC and I know that numpy installed in Anaconda environment accompanies mkl, I created `.venv`(independent virtual environment with virtualenv) and installed numpy with `pip install numpy` in this virtual environment.

However **it seems cx_Freeze consider not only the libraries from active virtual environment(`.venv`) but also from the libraries installed by Anaconda.**

This is the part of the log from execution of `python setup.py build`.

```
copying C:\Users\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_avx.1.dll -> C:\Users\Desktop\Python\P3-pid\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\numpy_mkl\mkl_avx.1.dll
copying C:\Users\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_avx2.1.dll -> C:\Users\Desktop\Python\P3-pid\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\numpy_mkl\mkl_avx2.1.dll
```

Is there anyone who knows how cx_Freeze detect the dependencies?
Or any solution to this problem is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you build with using pycharm terminal as pycharm creates venv in a sepeate path and you can see the difference.Also can you try with out anaconda environment in pycharm. if nothing works you can do like this in your setup.py file.

build_options = {'packages': ['flask', 'numpy'], 'excludes': ['sqlite3', 'idna', 'pandas', 'Tkinter','tcl','pytz','numpy-mkl'],

you can exclude the numpy-mkl package

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I actually got the solution from [cx_freeze github](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/1838), but will definitely try your suggestion too.